# Finite group with sequence of index 2 subgroups, such that the smallest one has odd order

Tags: group-theory

This is a homework question so please only provide me with some small hints. For a finite group $G$ suppose that $G_k \subset \dots \subset G_0 = G$ such that each $G_i$ has index 2 in $G_{i-1}$. The claim is that if $G_k$ has odd order then it is normal in $G$.

By the index assumption each $G_{i}$ is normal in the group above it. Thus I would like to transitively conclude $G_k$ is also normal in $G$. For this I would need to show that $G_k$ is characteristic in $G_{k-1}$, and then I could proceed by induction. Does this seem like a good first step? Can you give me a hint as to how to proceed?

Comment: Yes, this is a good first step. Continue in the same way moving from the bottom up, noticing each time that $G_k$ is normal and hence a characteristic subgroup in $G_i$, $i<k$.

Comment: My hunch is that $G_k$ doesn’t need to be characteristic in $G_{k-1}$. You can try to prove the result for p groups and then for a group of odd order.

Comment: @LawrenceMano I am not sure what you mean by your hunch! $G_k$ consists of the set of elements of odd order in $G_{k-1}$, so it is definitely characteristic in $G_{k-1}$.

Comment: Ok. Got your point. You are correct. Automorphism preserves order. Hence what you said is 100% correct.

Comment: @LawrenceMano can I ask you a follow-up question about this? I noticed that automorphisms preserve the order of _elements_ but how does it follow from this that $\phi(G_k) \leq G_k$? I understand all elements of the image are of odd order, but isn't some step missing here? That $G_k$ consists of all the odd order elements of $G$ or something like that?